# why I can't see the interface in Linux Debian

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I set an eth1 interface in Linux Debian, and I rebooted after that, but I don't see it when I would like to use the *sudo ifconfig*, or *ifconfig* command (as root) only the eth0 interface. The settings is the following:

[image]

And after the configuration and rebooting I see that:

[image]

Why I can't see the eth1 interface? Or if I would like to use the DHCP in a network, to set static ip address on server computer is neccessary?

Comment: I made a mistake: I deleted a 'k' character end of the 'loopbac', but I corrected it. But I continue can't see the eth1.

Comment: Did you created/configured the virtual device in virtualbox?

Comment: I set a NAT and Internal interfaces under the network option, and I put in a virtual disk. Not more.

Comment: There is only one NIC which the system calls `eth0`, and you want it to be called `eth1`?

Comment: No. I would like to two interfaces: 'eht0' and 'eth1' (and the 'lo' of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your config:

```
auto eht1
```

It should be instead:

```
auto eth1
```

So the interface just is not autoenabled. You can still see it with

```
ifconfig eth1
```

and bring it up with

```
ifconfig eth1 up
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you reboot your computer, the computer don't see the new settings of interfaces. (I don't know why.) But if you "reboot" the eth1 with *ifdown eth1* and after that *ifup eth1* you will see the new settings.

Comment: In my case, I used the command, "reboot", of the computer in the Terminal Window to solve the problem. Now, the computer shows as output the interface after using the "ifconfig" command.